# How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to move the page to a `<div>` element.

I have tried the next code to no avail:

```
document.getElementById("divFirst").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("divFirst").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: `visibility` and `display` are used for making elements (in)visible. Do you want to scroll the div in the screen?

Comment: What kind of focus? The same focus as you have when tabbing through form elements or focus in the sense of highlighting the element somehow? The only thing you do is to do display the element, which has not effect if it is already displayed.

Comment: Focus as scrolling into view?

Comment: [`el.scrollIntoView(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript to scroll long page to DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165/javascript-to-scroll-long-page-to-div)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can use an anchor to "focus" the div. I.e:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and then use the following javascript:

```js
// the next line is required to work around a bug in WebKit (Chrome / Safari)
location.href = "#";
location.href = "#myDiv";
```

Comment: Chrome (WebKit) has a bug which causes the page not to scroll once the anchor is set. Use: `location.href="#";location.href="#myDiv"`. Using `id="myDiv"` is preferred over `name="myDiv"` and works too.

Comment: I had this exact problem, but the WebKit "fix" causes a problem for me in FF 3.6.13.  It works without the "#" line, but if you add it, it goes to "#" and never attempts going to "#myDiv".  I'll stick with the solution without the "#", which is working for me... woohoo!

Comment: This doesn't work well for me because it adds all of these navigation events to the browser history and I can't easily go back to the previous page

Comment: I think 'AnhSirk Dasarp' below is a better method to scroll desired element to the top of the visible screen.

Comment: What if the scroller is in a inner div?

Comment: var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");elmnt.scrollIntoView();

Comment: schpet's answer below should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Cagy79 probably both should be used. In Chrome 97 for Windows 10 pc, `scrollIntoView();` wasn't enough to get the job done. It wouldn't scroll all the way into view. With this before the scroll into view it is better, still a bit jumpy... as I am typing this, I have the idea to use another `scrollIntoView();` to load the container, then scroll the subelement into view... Ima try it. Edit: Smoother than a baby's butt.

Comment: You can use `location.hash` too.
Here's [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash)

Comment: Hi from the future (now is 2023) .. :) does this thing work perfectly now, I am fed up with scrollTo, offsetTop and scrollIntoView bugs on Apple devices?

Comment: This doesn't work if you are already on a site with a "#" in it. For example buildbot uses "#...." to activate different views with different dynamic content and replacing the href fails then. While simply scrolling into view works.

Answer (score 588):

scrollIntoView works well:

```
document.getElementById("divFirst").scrollIntoView();
```

full reference in the MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: @CameronMcCluskie it's only the weird "scrollIntoViewOptions" (smooth scrolling, etc) that has exclusive firefox support. the basic use i have in my answer should work on almost anything.

Comment: I confirm, as of Apr-16, it works under Opera and Chrome too.

Comment: When using this solution and you have a fixed navbar at the top, you need to consider that as well. A different solution might be more suitable such as windows.scrollTo(posX, posY) with properly calculated posY.

Comment: Worked in Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

Comment: Don't see much of a difference in AnhSirk Dasarp's answer above and this one. They seem to behave exactly same to me.

Comment: I works in Edge too. I need only figure out if the element is already visible to avoid exceeding scrolls

Comment: [Here's another source (caniuse)](http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView) for browser compatibility of `scrollIntoView`

Comment: For some reason in my page this doesn't work. Only the solution of schpet (selected answer) works for me.

Answer (score 105):

#### For Chrome and Firefox

I've been looking a bit into this and I figured this one out which somehow feels like the most natural way to do it. Of course, this is my personal favorite scroll now. :)

```
const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
window.scroll({
  top: y,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

#### For IE, old Edge and old Safari supporters

Note that `window.scroll({ ...options })` is not supported on IE, Edge and Safari. In that case it's most likely best to use
[`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). (Supported on IE 6). You can *most likely* (read: untested) pass in options without any side effects.

These can of course be wrapped in a function that behaves according to which browser is being used.

Comment: Working like charm :)

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me with Chrome.

Comment: I wanted to take your solution, as it is possible to fine tune the position (in my case y-80). It seems, as  var element = document.getElementById("Div"); is missing in your example? Further it don't work with IE11. IE11 don't know window.scrollY - we have to use window.pageYOffset instead to receive a value. After I have changed that, I had various (not to comprehend) jquery errors (of course - as mostly - only in IE11. Therfore, I have implemented document.getElementById("divFirst").scrollIntoView(); and then $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 80); what works with all Browsers.

Comment: Not supported on Safari (passing options to `window.scroll`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updates the answer to include browser compatability.

Comment: Hey this code is to scroll up. What if we want to scroll down? I tried using 'bottom' property instead of 'top'. But that doesn't seem to be working... Any idea

Comment: @AnantShekhar Sure. If you want to scroll past the element so that the bottom is just out of view from the top then use `window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` insteadof `top`. If you want the bottom to be at the bottom of the page then it's `window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - window.innerHeight`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 48):

The best, shortest answer that what works even with animation effects:

```
var scrollDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetTop;
window.scrollTo({ top: scrollDiv, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

If you have a fixed nav bar, just subtract its height from top value, so if your fixed bar height is 70px, line 2 will look like:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: scrollDiv-70, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

**Explanation:** 
Line 1 gets the element position
Line 2 scroll to element position; `behavior` property adds a smooth animated effect

Comment: Really cool, but doesn't yet work on Safari and some other browsers. Does work with this polyfill https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll though. ;)

Comment: I think `offsetTop` is wrong in general. I think you want `getBoundingClientRect(...).y` or `.top`.

Answer (score 33):

We can implement by 3 Methods:

***Note:***

"automatic-scroll" => The particular element

"scrollable-div" => The scrollable area div

**Method 1:**

```
document.querySelector('.automatic-scroll').scrollIntoView({
     behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
location.href = "#automatic-scroll";
```

**Method 3:**

```
$('#scrollable-div').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#automatic-scroll').offset().top - $('#scrollable-div').offset().top + 
   $('#scrollable-div').scrollTop()
})
```

***Important notice***: method 1 & method 2 will be useful if the scrollable area height is "**auto**". Method 3 is useful if we using the scrollable area height like "**calc(100vh - 200px)**".

Answer (score 18):

You can set focus to element. It works better than `scrollIntoView`

`node.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')`

`node.focus()`

`node.removeAttribute('tabindex')`

Comment: Oh man, you saved my day. Tested lots of stuff but this one was the only thing that worked for me and it's supported any all the browsers. Btw I created an input and gave 1px height and width and did focus on the input.it works great. Thanks

Comment: actually it's a bad approaching for accessibility, and you cannot add smooth animation... i would try using window.scrollTo, but it might be error-prone on react apps since your component wont scroll due to its in another screen element, such as 'root', or whatever... the best here would be using scrollIntoView... although it doesn't work on iOS currently...

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
var divFirst = document.getElementById("divFirst");
divFirst.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
divFirst.style.display = 'block';  
divFirst.tabIndex = "-1";  
divFirst.focus();
```

e.g @:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Vgrey/

Comment: I only want to emphasize that the DOM property is `element.tabIndex` but not `element.tabindex`; the second one works on Firefox but not on Chrome (at least when I tried it some time ago). Of course, used as an HTML attribute both `tabIndex` and `tabindex` work (and on XHTML, `tabindex` must be used)

Comment: Doesn't work if the div is already focused. Need `div.blur()` first.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a function that can include an optional offset for those fixed headers. No external libraries needed.

```
function scrollIntoView(selector, offset = 0) {
  window.scroll(0, document.querySelector(selector).offsetTop - offset);
}
```

You can grab the height of an element using JQuery and scroll to it.

```
var headerHeight = $('.navbar-fixed-top').height();
scrollIntoView('#some-element', headerHeight)
```

**Update March 2018**

Scroll to this answer without using JQuery

```
scrollIntoView('#answer-44786637', document.querySelector('.top-bar').offsetHeight)
```

Answer (score 6):

To scroll to a given element, just made this javascript only solution below.

Simple usage:

```
EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalToElementById('signup_form', 20);
```

Engine object (you can fiddle with filter, fps values):

```
/**
 *
 * Created by Borbás Geri on 12/17/13
 * Copyright (c) 2013 eppz! development, LLC.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */


var EPPZScrollTo =
{
    /**
     * Helpers.
     */
    documentVerticalScrollPosition: function()
    {
        if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset; // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) return document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6 (standards mode).
        if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop; // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8.
        return 0; // None of the above.
    },

    viewportHeight: function()
    { return (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat") ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight; },

    documentHeight: function()
    { return (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight; },

    documentMaximumScrollPosition: function()
    { return this.documentHeight() - this.viewportHeight(); },

    elementVerticalClientPositionById: function(id)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        var rectangle = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return rectangle.top;
    },

    /**
     * Animation tick.
     */
    scrollVerticalTickToPosition: function(currentPosition, targetPosition)
    {
        var filter = 0.2;
        var fps = 60;
        var difference = parseFloat(targetPosition) - parseFloat(currentPosition);

        // Snap, then stop if arrived.
        var arrived = (Math.abs(difference) <= 0.5);
        if (arrived)
        {
            // Apply target.
            scrollTo(0.0, targetPosition);
            return;
        }

        // Filtered position.
        currentPosition = (parseFloat(currentPosition) * (1.0 - filter)) + (parseFloat(targetPosition) * filter);

        // Apply target.
        scrollTo(0.0, Math.round(currentPosition));

        // Schedule next tick.
        setTimeout("EPPZScrollTo.scrollVerticalTickToPosition("+currentPosition+", "+targetPosition+")", (1000 / fps));
    },

    /**
     * For public use.
     *
     * @param id The id of the element to scroll to.
     * @param padding Top padding to apply above element.
     */
    scrollVerticalToElementById: function(id, padding)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element == null)
        {
            console.warn('Cannot find element with id \''+id+'\'.');
            return;
        }

        var targetPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition() + this.elementVerticalClientPositionById(id) - padding;
        var currentPosition = this.documentVerticalScrollPosition();

        // Clamp.
        var maximumScrollPosition = this.documentMaximumScrollPosition();
        if (targetPosition > maximumScrollPosition) targetPosition = maximumScrollPosition;

        // Start animation.
        this.scrollVerticalTickToPosition(currentPosition, targetPosition);
    }
};
```

Comment: @codeWithMe Yap, it is more like an iOS-like code, where actual quantity does not matter, so you can go ahead and name everything after what it does / contains. I prefer that over shortness.

Answer (score 5):

JS:

```
document.getElementById('targetid').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

USE with inline HTML :

```
<p class="text-notification">Some Notification <span style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" onClick="document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});">Go to target<span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @caveman's solution

```
const element = document.getElementById('theelementsid');

if (element) {
    window.scroll({
        top: element.scrollTop,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A method i often use to scroll a container to its contents.

```
/**
@param {HTMLElement} container : element scrolled.
@param {HTMLElement} target : element where to scroll.
@param {number} [offset] : scroll back by offset
*/
var scrollAt=function(container,target,offset){
    if(container.contains(target)){
        var ofs=[0,0];
        var tmp=target;
        while (tmp!==container) {
            ofs[0]+=tmp.offsetWidth;
            ofs[1]+=tmp.offsetHeight;
            tmp=tmp.parentNode;
        }
        container.scrollTop = Math.max(0,ofs[1]-(typeof(offset)==='number'?offset:0));
    }else{
        throw('scrollAt Error: target not found in container');
    }
};
```

if your whish to override globally, you could also do :

```
HTMLElement.prototype.scrollAt=function(target,offset){
    if(this.contains(target)){
        var ofs=[0,0];
        var tmp=target;
        while (tmp!==this) {
            ofs[0]+=tmp.offsetWidth;
            ofs[1]+=tmp.offsetHeight;
            tmp=tmp.parentNode;
        }
        container.scrollTop = Math.max(0,ofs[1]-(typeof(offset)==='number'?offset:0));
    }else{
        throw('scrollAt Error: target not found in container');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to scroll to the bottom of a list that is inside a div, you can do this.

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div> 
</div>
<button>Scroll To</button>

    <script> 
        const btn = document.querySelector("button");
        const container = document.querySelector(".container"); 
        btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        const toplast = document.querySelector(".container").lastElementChild;
        toplast.scrollIntoView();
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQhoV.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Focus can be set on interactive elements only... Div only represent a logical section of the page.

Perhaps you can set the borders around div or change it's color to simulate a focus. And yes Visiblity is not focus.

Answer (score 1):

Due to behavior "smooth" doesn't work in Safari, Safari ios, Explorer. I usually write a simple function utilizing requestAnimationFrame

```
(function(){
    var start;
    var startPos = 0;

    //Navigation scroll page to element
    function scrollTo(timestamp, targetTop){
      if(!start) start = timestamp
      var runtime = timestamp - start
      var progress = Math.min(runtime / 700, 1)

      window.scroll(0, startPos + (targetTop * progress) )

      if(progress >= 1){
        return;
      }else {
        requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp){
            scrollTo(timestamp, targetTop)
        })
      }
   };

  navElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    var target = e.target  //or this 
    var targetTop = _(target).getBoundingClientRect().top
    startPos = window.scrollY

    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp){
        scrollTo(timestamp, targetTop)
    })
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

**window.scrollBy()**

An alternative to `window.scroll()` in @caveman's answer is `window.scrollBy()`. The following scrolls the browser window to position the target element at the top of the viewport.

```
const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.scrollBy({
    top: y,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

The `window.scrollBy()` method has the same wide [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy#browser_compatibility) as `window.scroll()`.

As per the [notes section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy#notes) of the MDN entry for the `scrollBy` method:

> `window.scrollBy()` scrolls by a particular amount, whereas `window.scroll()` scrolls to an absolute position in the document.

The formula used in @caveman's post to calculate the scroll-to value is:

```
const y = window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

This formula gets the current absolute position (`window.scrollY`) and adds the delta of the `element`'s [bounding rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#return_value) top position (relative to the top of the viewport).

The retrieval of the value returned by `window.scrollY` (the current absolute position) is not necessary as the y-scroll position of the browser window will only change by the value returned by `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` (i.e. a relative value change).

[image]

### Positioning element at top, vertical middle, or bottom

The following sample shows the positioning of a target element at the top, vertical middle, or bottom of the viewport using the `window.scrollBy()` method.

```js
const headerElem = document.querySelector("header");

document.querySelectorAll("form.scroll-by > button")
  .forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", scrollByClickListener));

function scrollByClickListener() {
  const targetId = this.getAttribute("data-target-id");
  if (!targetId) {
    return;
  }

  const targetElem = document.querySelector(`#${targetId}`);
  if (!targetElem) {
    return;
  }

  const position = this.getAttribute("data-position");
  if (!position) {
    return;
  }

  scrollElemIntoView(targetElem, position);
}

function scrollElemIntoView(targetElem, position) {
  let scrollByY = 0;

  switch (position) {
    case "top":
      scrollByY = targetElem.getBoundingClientRect().top -
        headerElem.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      break;
    case "middle":
      const rect = targetElem.getBoundingClientRect();
      scrollByY = rect.top -
        window.innerHeight / 2 +
        rect.height / 2 -
        headerElem.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2;
      break;
    case "bottom":
      scrollByY = targetElem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom -
        window.innerHeight;
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }

  window.scrollBy({
    top: scrollByY,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

form.scroll-by {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

form.scroll-by button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#target-elements>div {
  height: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header><span>Fixed Header Element</span></header>
<form class="scroll-by">
  <button type="button" data-position="top" data-target-id="target-4">Top (target 4)</button>
  <button type="button" data-position="middle" data-target-id="target-3">Vertical Middle (target 3)</button>
  <button type="button" data-position="bottom" data-target-id="target-6">Bottom (target 6)</button>
</form>
<div id="target-elements">
  <div id="target-1">Target 1</div>
  <div id="target-2">Target 2</div>
  <div id="target-3">Target 3</div>
  <div id="target-4">Target 4</div>
  <div id="target-5">Target 5</div>
  <div id="target-6">Target 6</div>
  <div id="target-7">Target 7</div>
  <div id="target-8">Target 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you add a tabindex to your div, it will be able to get focus:

```
<div class="divFirst" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```

I don't think it's valid though, tabindex can be applied only to a, area, button, input, object, select, and textarea. But give it a try.

Comment: In HTML5 `tabindex` is a "core attribute", which are "global attributes" (attributes that are common to all elements in the HTML language). See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/global-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus on a div. You can only focus on an input element in that div. Also, you need to use element.focus() instead of display()

Comment: You can make a `<div>` focusable if using the `tabindex` attribute. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/editing.html#attr-tabindex

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a lot, this is what finally worked for me:

1. Find/locate div in your dom which has scroll bar.
   For me, it looked like this : 
   "div class="table_body table_body_div" scroll_top="0" scroll_left="0" style="width: 1263px; height: 499px;"
2. I located it with this xpath : //div[@class='table_body table_body_div']
3. Used JavaScript to execute scrolling like this :
   (JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];",element,2000);

2000 is the no of pixels I wanted to scroll towards the right.
Use scrollTop instead of scrollLeft if you want to scroll your div down.

Note : I tried using scrollIntoView but it didn't work properly because my webpage had multiple divs. It will work if you have only one main window where focus lies.
This is the best solution I have come across if you don't want to use jQuery which I didn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

**Old way of implementing scroll using Javascript**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btnToScroll');
const section = document.querySelector('.scrollToSection');
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        sectionCords = section.getBoundingClientRect();
        window.scrollTo(  // we are passing one object into window.scrollTo with required values
            {
             left:sectionCords.left + window.pageXOffset, //if pageXOffset showing deprication warning then use scrollX 
             top:sectionCords.top + window.pageYOffset, //if pageYOffset showing deprication warning then use scrollY
             behavior:"smooth" //behavior of scroll
            }
    });
```

- getBoundingClientRect() will give us the an object with current positions of the element relative to viewport
- scrollTo is a global function available on window object
- window.pageXOffset will give us the the distance in px we have scrolled from extreme left corner of the window
- window.pageYOffset will give us the the distance in px we have scrolled from extreme top corner of the window

**Modern way of implementing scroll using Javascript** (works in modern web browsers)

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btnToScroll');
const section = document.querySelector('.scrollToSection');
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    section.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"}); //will smoothly scroll to desired section
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to use html, you could just use this:

```
a href="samplewebsite.com/subdivision.html#id
```

and make it an html link to the specific element id. Its basically `getElementById` html version.

Answer (score -4):

try this function

```
function navigate(divId) {
$j('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $j("#"+divId).offset().top }, 1500);
}
```

Pass the div id as parameter it will work I am using it already

Comment: what library is `$j` from?

Comment: I assume the $j references jQuery - the question states it needs Javascript.