# adding favourite reverts to top of the screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function on my rails app where a user can add a favourite by pressing a button.  Once the favourite is added, the page reloads to the top of the screen.  The guideline that the user has favourited could be half way down the screen and it's annoying for them to then have to start viewing at the top again.  Is there a way for it just to be changed to 'favourite' but stay where the user is on the page?

In index.html.erb (views)

```
<% if !current_user.favourite_guidelines.select{|f| f.guideline_id==guideline.id}.any? %>
                    <%= link_to guidelines_favourite_path(guideline_id: guideline.id, type: "favourite"), method: "get", class: "btn btn-small main" do%>
                    <i class="icon icon-star"></i> Favourite
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <% if current_user.favourite_guidelines.select{|f| f.guideline_id==guideline.id}.any? %>
                <%= link_to guidelines_favourite_path(guideline_id: guideline.id, type: "unfavourite"), method: "get", class: "btn btn-small main" do%>
                <i class="icon-star-empty"></i> Unfavourite
                <% end %>
```

guidelines_controller.rb

```
def favourite
   type = params[:type]
   if type == "favourite"
      @guideline= Guideline.find_by_id(params[:guideline_id])
          current_user.favourite_guidelines.build(:guideline_id => @guideline.id).save
           redirect_to :back


    elsif type == "unfavourite"
      @guideline= Guideline.find_by_id(params[:guideline_id])

     current_user.favourite_guidelines.where(:guideline_id => @guideline.id).destroy_all
     redirect_to :back

    else
    # Type missing, nothing happens
   redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to` loads the page, that's why it's at the top.

- you can use javascript to scroll to the element if you'd like after a
  redirect. i'm assuming you'd do something like this:

  [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript)

OR

- you can do an AJAX call and that way the page won't redirect. you would then just have the response update the page the the user is on, and so the user wouldn't be redirected anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You would typically make this happen by using AJAX so that only part of your page is reloaded, keeping the user's scroll position. The Rails Guides have some incomplete information here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html

There's also a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) on the subject. They're very helpful and worth buying.