# pdfjs: How to create more than one canvas to show all the pages?

Tags: angularjs, canvas, pdf.js

I am following the approach of
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480469/how-to-display-whole-pdf-not-only-one-page-with-pdf-js/19099203?noredirect=1#comment44977782_19099203). The problem is that all the pages are in first canvas. This is because I have only one canvas and I am not sure how I can generate more canvas  one after other?

```
 function handlePages(page)
        {
            var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            page.render({ canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport });

            //Add it to the web page
            div.appendChild( canvas);
                //Move to next page
                currPage++;
                if ( $scope.pdfDoc !== null && currPage <= numPages )
                {
                    $scope.pdfDoc.getPage( currPage ).then( handlePages );
                }



        }
```

Comment: you cut out part of the code from the linked answer that you took this from. notice the `document.createElement( "canvas" )`. That creates a new canvas for every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cut out part of the code from the linked answer that you took this from. notice the `document.createElement( "canvas" )`. That creates a new canvas for every page.