# using mozilla PDFJS how to show all pages not a single

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, pdf.js

Please Help, I tried Lots of solution to **show all pages** one by one but **I get different error**,
so now I'm using demo code of **pdfjs** and its work for **one page**, can anyone know how to display it all pages.

**I tried this solution but not work for me**
[How to display whole PDF (not only one page) with PDF.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480469/how-to-display-whole-pdf-not-only-one-page-with-pdf-js/46653905)

```js
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = 'demo.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  
  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {

    options = options || { scale: 1 };
        
    function renderPage(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        wrapper.className = "canvas-wrapper";
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        wrapper.appendChild(canvas)
        canvasContainer.appendChild(wrapper);
        
        page.render(renderContext);
    }
    
    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }

    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);

}   


renderPDF('https://res.cloudinary.com/sivadass/image/upload/v1519136548/hr-sample-pdf.pdf', document.getElementById('holder'));
```

```css
#holder{
  background: #eee;
  padding: 32px 0 16px 0;
}
.canvas-wrapper{
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
canvas{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

**I hope, it will help you!**
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.0.385/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
  <div id="holder"></div>
```