# Render the whole PDF (all pages) with PDFjs

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am using PDFjs to display my PDF.

By default, it render page by page. But I would like to display the whole PDF (when the document is less than X pages long).
I am not good at all in Javascript and did not find anything to do that.

Here is the code that render one page at the same time :

```
    <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

    <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

    <script>
            // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
            // header on that server.
            var url = '/my_pdf.pdf';

            // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
            var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

            // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

            var pdfDoc = null,
                pageNum = 1,
                pageRendering = false,
                pageNumPending = null,
                scale = 2,
                canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            /**
             * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
             * @param num Page number.
             */
            function renderPage(num) {
                pageRendering = true;
                // Using promise to fetch the page
                pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
                    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    // Render PDF page into canvas context
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: ctx,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

                    // Wait for rendering to finish
                    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                        pageRendering = false;
                        if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                            // New page rendering is pending
                            renderPage(pageNumPending);
                            pageNumPending = null;
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Update page counters
                document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
            }

            /**
             * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
             * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
             */
            function queueRenderPage(num) {
                if (pageRendering) {
                    pageNumPending = num;
                } else {
                    renderPage(num);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
             */
            pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
                pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
                document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

                // Initial/first page rendering
                renderPage(pageNum);
            });
      </script>
```

I have found this topic but it uses an old version and I cannot use it properly : [How to display whole PDF (not only one page) with PDF.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480469/how-to-display-whole-pdf-not-only-one-page-with-pdf-js)

I have been struggling with this code for several days
Thanks for you help :)