# Display whole Base64 PDF in mobile, embedded

Tags: base64, jspdf

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099203/10034413), the difference is I have a base64 File.

I tested with a 3 pages PDFfile and it creates 3 canvas elements, but not show the PDF pages.

I searched for some hours to find any solutions, but without success.

There is my full code (its only a test page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>PDF.js Previous/Next example</h1>

</body>

<script>

var pdfData = atob('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');

var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});

var currPage = 1; //Pages are 1-based not 0-based
var numPages = 0;
var thePDF = null;

//This is where you start
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    //Set PDFJS global object (so we can easily access in our page functions
        thePDF = pdf;

        //How many pages it has
        numPages = pdf.numPages;

        //Start with first page
        pdf.getPage( 1 ).then( handlePages );
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});


function handlePages(page)
{
    //This gives us the page's dimensions at full scale
    var viewport = page.getViewport( 1.5 );

    //We'll create a canvas for each page to draw it on
    var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //Draw it on the canvas
    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});

    //Add it to the web page
    document.body.appendChild( canvas );

    //Move to next page
    currPage++;
    if ( thePDF !== null && currPage <= numPages )
    {
        thePDF.getPage( currPage ).then( handlePages );
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i find the problem

```
var scale = 1.5;

var viewport = page.getViewport( {scale: scale} );
```

Final Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>PDF.js Previous/Next example</h1>

</body>
<script>

var pdfData = atob('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');

var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});

var currPage = 1; //Pages are 1-based not 0-based
var numPages = 0;
var thePDF = null;

//This is where you start
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    //Set PDFJS global object (so we can easily access in our page functions
        thePDF = pdf;

        //How many pages it has
        numPages = pdf.numPages;

        //Start with first page
        pdf.getPage( currPage ).then( handlePages );
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});

var scale = 1.5;
function handlePages(page)
{
    //This gives us the page's dimensions at full scale
    var viewport = page.getViewport( {scale: scale} );

    //We'll create a canvas for each page to draw it on
    var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
    canvas.style.display = "block";
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //Draw it on the canvas
    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});

    //Add it to the web page
    document.body.appendChild( canvas );

    //Move to next page
    currPage++;
    if ( thePDF !== null && currPage <= numPages )
    {
        thePDF.getPage( currPage ).then( handlePages );
    }
}
</script>

</html>
```