# How To Adjust a User's view using Javascript and Anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I've got the following Script:

```
<div id=tbl name=tbl style="overflow:hidden;display:none">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function sizeTbl() {

    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
    var icon = document.getElementById('toggle-table');
    if (icon.src === 'up_arrow.png'){

        tbl.style.display = 'none';
        icon.src = 'down_arrow.png';
    }
    else {
        tbl.style.display = 'block';
        icon.src = 'up_arrow.png';    
    }
}

// -->
</script> 
<br>

<a href="javascript:sizeTbl()"><img src="down_arrow.png" id="toggle-table"></a>
```

This does exactly what I want by having a section of a website hidden from a user's view until the click the "down" arrow.  Then when they click said arrow, the content expands and the "down" arrow changes to an "up" arrow.  Once the user hits the "up" arrow, the content hides again and the arrow returns to a "down" arrow.

The trick is that the content is quite long so when the user closes the section by hitting the "up" arrow, the section the table resides in shifts further up than the user's view.  I'd like to solve that using Anchor tags so whenever either arrow is hit, the user's view is adjusted to the top of the section.  Any ideas how I can go about that using the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using slideUp and slideDown with jQuery?

Comment: So far I'm actually not using JQuery on the site at all but this would be a good option if I can't find a workaround soon.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'm going to suggest window.scrollto() [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8KuA/4/)
Instead of using an anchor with a hash, use any element with an id

```
function sizeTbl() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
    var icon = document.getElementById('toggle-table');
    if (icon.innerText === 'hide'){
        tbl.style.display = 'none';
        icon.innerText = 'show';
    }
    else {
        tbl.style.display = 'block';
        icon.innerText = 'hide';    
    }
    var x = getOffset( document.getElementById('bottom') );
    console.log(x);
    window.scrollTo(x.left, x.top); // values are x,y-offset
}

function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: sorry dude it didn't work and I tried using <a name="..."> as well as href.

Comment: there's a jquery plugin called scrollTo, it utilizes the scrolltop function and you can tell it to scroll to any element on the screen.

Comment: Any other ideas of accomplishing it without using JQuery?  I know that's a strange concept but for various reasons I won't get into I'm being asked to accomplish this without calling JQuery up.

Comment: @Slider257 what do you mean when you say it doesn't work. Do you get any error messages in console? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @jasonscript - jsfiddle attached.  Did not get any errors from the console but the view did not adjust as it was supposed to.  http://jsfiddle.net/f8KuA/2/

Comment: I'm not too sure about the cross browser compatability of the offsets and the scrollTo functions ... but I used it in Firefox and it worked.

Comment: @AlanAsher - Mind checking that jsfiddle to ensure I'm doing it correctly?  I'm also working in Firefox but when I tested the code you suggested it did not work in Safari either.  Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly?

Comment: @Slider257 I made an update and saved a new JSFiddle here [http://jsfiddle.net/f8KuA/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/f8KuA/4/) I also updated the answer with the code changes

Comment: Ok, I re read that and see that you saw my changes, and so. yes, I just went there and it's running.  There is a rather important change of using an id on the link so instead of `<a name="bottom">` you'd have to make it an ID `<a id="bottom"></a>`