# Not updating url on click an in DOM element referencing anchor

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to navigate to an existing element in html document with the id that matches the href of an anchor and still not update the url in the address bar?

This is causing not to be able to always render the a homeview with subviews nested inside it when one refreshes the page. When page is refreshed on homeview even with the defined in the mainrouter.js route in the address bar the page is not rendered at all(in backbone/require app).

Comment: Use `window.scrollTo()` to scroll to the coordinates of the element.

Comment: Are there not any other way to use still using ids to locate destination?

Comment: I don't think so. You can either put the ID in the hash of the URL, or you can scroll to it explicitly with Javascript.

Comment: being have to know coordinates is not handy, devices change.

Comment: You can use Javascript to get the coordinates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript