# Calling both a function and an onpage anchor on a <button>

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that calculates some stuff, and I need to initiate this (call the function) but at the same time I need to scroll to where I have the results.

I need smooth scrolling so I have a separate function handling this.

I've tried the following:

```
<button id="btn" onClick="calculate(); window.location='#results';">Calculate</button>
```

While it both calculates AND scrolls, it doesn't activate my smooth scrolling function, for some reason, and just hard/regular jumps to .

I am using this https://github.com/Yappli/smooth-scroll for smooth scrolling, where it turns every #link into a smooth scroll.

How do I make this work?

I am doing all of this with no jQuery, as it needs to be super light weight.

Comment: where are you calling the smooth scrolling function? no evidence of that in the snippet you posted, just calculate() and a JUMP to #results

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry. I am using this https://github.com/Yappli/smooth-scroll where it turns all # links into smooth scrolling. The code snippet is physically placed before </body>

Comment: THought I had an answer - but it was wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript/20670708#20670708 - you wont need your smooth-scroll javascript for that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the Smooth-Scroll so that it looks for a class instead of `a` elements.

Change line 19 from:

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
```

To:

```
links = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-to'),
```

You could do both, but you'll need to merge the two `HTMLCollection`s, something like this:

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
classes = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-to'),
links = [].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(links), Array.prototype.slice.call(classes));
```