# Scroll all nested scrollbars to bring an HTML element into view

Tags: javascript

I can’t wrap my head around it.

The element exists in a nested hierarchy of multiple scrollable DIV elements rather than in a single scrollable document window.

One of my headaches is how `scrolled.offsetParent` is `document.body` (colour `papayawhip` in test code below) rather than `scrollable` (colour `pink`).

Solutions to this problem based on JQuery and other libraries are acceptable only as complementary – for the benefit of other users, not mine.

### Test code

(Original location: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/262amaxL/5/).)

```js
function ReportExpression(ExpressionString) {
    return ExpressionString + " == " + eval(ExpressionString) + "\n";
}

function ButtonClick() {
    var scrollable = document.querySelector('#scrollable');
    var scrolled = document.querySelector('#scrolled');
    alert(
        ReportExpression("scrollable.scrollTop") +
        ReportExpression("scrolled.offsetTop") +
        ReportExpression("(scrolled.offsetParent == document.body)")
    );
    scrollable.scrollTop = scrolled.offsetTop;
}
```

```css
html {background-color: white;}
body {text-align: center; background-color: papayawhip;}
#page {display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 500px; height: 500px;
    overflow: auto; background-color: powderblue; padding: 10px;}
#scrollable {height: 500px; overflow: auto; background-color: pink;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <button onClick="ButtonClick();">Scroll</button>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="scrollable">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <text id="scrolled">I want to scroll all scrollbars to this element.</text>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Articles that I have studied

1. [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript)
2. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
3. [How to scroll to an element inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)

Comment: How do I embed the above test code to let StackOverflow users try it live?

Comment: You can try setting up a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) and pasting the link here.

Comment: I’ve just discovered [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). It would solve my problem if it weren’t a Working Draft specification.

Comment: Just realised that `eval(ExpressionString)` in my code works as expected only by some lucky stroke. It shouldn’t evaluate expressions that contain local variables from other functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/804gtjp5/)?:

```
function ButtonClick() {
  var page = document.querySelector('#page');
  var scrollable = document.querySelector('#scrollable');
  var scrolled = document.querySelector('#scrolled');
  page.scrollTop = scrollable.offsetTop-page.offsetTop;
  scrollable.scrollTop = scrolled.offsetTop-scrollable.offsetTop;
}
```

Comment: I love it! Not only your solution works, but also makes me comprehend offset relationships. I like all answers in this thread so far. Shame I can’t upvote any due to my novice status.

Comment: Alright. I’m picking your answer as my favourite. @Joey’s solution is awesomely simple but is less suitable for bookmarklets because a bookmarklet needs to deal with received HTML code without necessary HREF anchors. And yours has an extra educational value for me.

Comment: I have created a library function based on your solution: `function ScrollDivTreeIntoView(dt) {for (var i = dt.length - 1; i >= 1; --i) dt[i].scrollTop = dt[i - 1].offsetTop - dt[i].offsetTop;}`. It reduces scrolling the whole nested DIV tree to a one-liner: `ScrollDivTreeIntoView([scrolled, scrollable, page])`. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/262amaxL/7/))

Comment: For my own reference when I need this kind of thing in the future: page = container with scrollbar, scrollable = nested container with scrollbar, scrolled = target element to scroll to. Make sure `scrollBehavior: "smooth"` is set on the containers with scrollbars or the animation won't be smooth. `scrollIntoView` was hot garbage, and not well supported across browsers for certain settings.

Answer (score 4):

Just make it like a href anchor and go to that anchor.

```
<button onClick="document.location+='#scrolled';return false;">Scroll</button>
```

Comment: To be honest... that will do the job too. So simple that I haven’t thought about it. A bit dodgy in bookmarklets though because will require converting  existing HTML elements into HREF anchors. Perhaps that’s why I haven’t thought about it. But it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to the first of the links you said you studied, I have applied one solution from there.

```
    element = document.getElementById("scrollable");
    alignWithTop = true;
    element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop);

    elementB = document.getElementById("scrolled");
    alignWithTopB = true;
    elementB.scrollIntoView(alignWithTopB);
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yt22fwc0/

Comment: I would love this function but, according to [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), it’s a Working Draft specification. In addition, @AnchalAgrawal said in that thread: “I tried using scrollIntoView but it didn't work properly because my webpage had multiple divs. It will work if you have only one main window where focus lies. This is the best solution I have come across if you don't want to use jQuery which I didn't want to.”

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Also, to fix the "Uncaught ReferenceError: ButtonClick is not defined" in JSFiddle, click on the Gear icon next to JAVASCRIPT and change the load type to "No wrap - <In head>".

Comment: 1. I may still use your solution in my personal bookmarklets because it works and is very convenient. 2. My JSFiddle now works. Thanks!