# Javascript - is there an alternative for element.scroll or element.scrollTo in Safari?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I've just noticed that the `.scroll` and `scrollTo` methods are `undefined` when invoked on DOM elements in Safari. Chrome and Firefox seem to handle the issue right.

I've added this [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/wemewayawe/1/edit?html,js,console,output) to ilustrate the problem. Open it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari to and check the Console panel. I'm on a mac, by the way.

Do you know of any alternative or woraround?

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript

Comment: @spencer.sm I actually need to scroll horizontally from javascript

Comment: I'd recommend updating your question to include that detail.

Comment: @GOTO0 thank you for your answer, this did the trick for me. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) and [`.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) properties are [well supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t35) in current browsers, including Safari, and can be used to get or change horizontal and vertical scrolling offset.

```
element.scrollLeft = x;
element.scrollTop  = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is throwing undefined for me as well. I think these methods are only `window` methods [see](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) w3 schools reference here.

Comment: you are right. Looks like I have some extra functionality enabled in Chrome via flags. Anyway, I need to scroll horizontally via javascript, any thoughts on that?