# Javascript scroll to element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a little slide menu. Each slide is 100vh and I want to scroll to each slide with my menu.

I did the query and the listeners and now I try to make each click go to the right #slide.

The number of slides will be dynamic.

I am not a javascript superhero so I hope I started all good !

Thanks in advance for your help and advices.

```js
let sections= document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
let nbrMenuLinks = sections.length;

for(i = 0; i < nbrMenuLinks; i++) {
    const li  = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'scroll-item';
    li.id = 'btn'+(i+1);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i+1)));
    document.querySelector('#slide-menu').appendChild(li);
    li.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById(`slide3`)));
    });
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curtop];
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="slide-menu"></ul>
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide 2</h2>
</div>
<div id="slide3" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide 3</h2>
</div>
<div id="slide4" class="slide">
  <h2>Slide 4</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Hum ok I thought it was easier than this ! I should try more basic stuffs or work with slick :D

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, now it works, I just need to access to the ID of the slide dynamically...

Comment: Hi Reggio, welcome to StackOverflow. To help people in future with the same problem, would you be able to edit your answer to include your solution?

Comment: And as for scrolling to the relevant section dynamically, you’ve hard-coded `section3` into your loop in the example, why not use `section${i+1}`? Or even better, wrap the slides in a container, and access them by index, rather than relying on numerical string IDs: `document.getElementById('slides').children[i]`.