# Replace #! anchor characters

Tags: url, hyperlink, navigation, anchor

I am building a simple menu. Among layouts I've considered is a plain-jane dropdown that looks like this for numerous items:

```
    <li>
      <a href="#!">Fare</a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li><a href="tomatoes.php">Tomatoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="cheese.php">Cheese</a></li>
        <li><a href="bacon.php">Bacon</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

This seems very functional, but there are often the #! characters appended to the URLs when I navigate among pages.  Of course if I eliminate those characters, the dropdown behavior stops altogether.

Are there other means for coding anchors to eliminate these from URLs?

Comment: You can use `javaScript` --  And use selectors to `.scroll()` to the desired element.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm sure you are right.  If only I knew where to begin.

Comment: Check out [Caveman's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript)