# How to add a scroll function with JS?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to add a scroll function to my landing page so that when the navi bar link is clicked, it smoothly scrolls to the section. instead of CSS, I should use JS, 'addEventListener','preventDefault' and ''`scrollIntoView()` to achieve this. I've been trying and trying for days, it just dosen't work, please help me!

PS: I have fixed this problem, thank you you guys

```js
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  }); 
  document.documentElement.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  }); 
}
```

Comment: When i click on section1 it goes to section 1 , seame for 2,3 and 4. So whats not working?

Comment: it has to smooth scroll to section, but not jump to......

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reprodcude your problem, belongs _directly_ into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform like codepen.

Comment: sorry! I'll do it right next time!

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the code that you commented, but also changed a major part when you created the menu links.

```
const clickItems =  document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');

for (const clickItem of clickItems) {
      clickItem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(e.currentTarget.dataset.href).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    });
  }
```

The main difference is that I changed your `href` attribute in the menu links into a `data-href` attribute, otherwise the native behavior would scroll down to your sections, just like any link would do.

```
navList += `<li id="${sectionName}"> <a class="navbar__menu menu__link" data-href="#${section.id}">${sectionName}</a></li>`;
```

Comment: Hi! just found out the click and scroll works in CodePen view fine, but not in chrome...

Comment: Sorry, but I need more debugging information than "not in Chrome". Do some console.logs on the right places, check any error messages, or add breakpoints and really debug your own code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and sorry that I didn't give enough information. I did the two changes in CodePen als you told me, and the scroll function works perfectly, as well as other functions ,  then I copied and pasted the same code from CodePen in VS code , saved locally and  opened the page  with browser(chrome and Firefox), but when I click the navi menu, it doesn't  react at all, neither jump nor scroll to the section. when i change data-href back to href and delete the scroll function code, it works again like before(click and jump to the section).

Comment: I try to debug with chrome developer tool but couldn't find out anything. I don't undertand why the code with your changes works perfectly in CodePen, but not in browser...

Comment: Is it possible that the script executes before the HTML have loaded into the DOM. Will it return an empty array (really: node list) if you do a `console.log(clickItems)` after clickItems have been declared? That's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the element and move directly

```
document.getElementById("myElement").scrollIntoView();
```

"behavior" Defines the transition animation. One of auto or smooth. Defaults to auto.

Post: [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292000/4896080)