# Can't get coordinates of html element

Tags: javascript

I tried to get the coordinates of **Block-1** and scroll the page to it, but I did something wrong =( How to get the html coordinates of the **Block-1** element and scroll the page to it?

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.Block-1');
let coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
elem.style.top = coords.bottom + 'px';


window.scrollTo({
  top: elem,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

```css
.Block-1 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Block-1">

  Scroll here

</div>
```

Comment: `scrollTo( { top: elem } )` <-- `elem` is not a `number`. I think you want `top: coords.top`.

Comment: i am newbie how to use debugger?

Comment: Press F12 or <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd> in your browser.

Comment: @alderman - it's more complicated than can be explained in a comment, but if you search "how to use Chrome debugger" (or your browser of choice) I'm sure you'll find several tutorials.

Comment: how to get the coordinates of an html element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where on the right track. The top property of the `scrollTo()` is the top property of the `getBoundingClientRect()`. So, `top: coords.top`.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.Block-1:nth-child(2)');
let coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

window.scrollTo({
  top: coords.top,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

```css
.Block-1 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Block-1">

  Not here

</div>

<div class="Block-1">

  Scroll here

</div>

<div class="Block-1">

  Not here

</div>
```