# Make content in an iFrame start at the bottom when page loaded

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, scroll

I have an iframe, well it's exactly an iframe, its a div with a scroll overflow.

I want it to start scrolled to the bottom when the page is loaded

Is this possible with Jquery?

And if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this solution: [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div). Andsien's answer uses jQuery and is just one line of code; here's the code he gave wrapped in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mydiv").scrollTop($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I did one before. I used the following library:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html