# Custom Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to replace the dredged scrollbar that shows on PC web browsers with something a little nicer.

I have a div that has a "width" set and "overflow-x" set to "scroll", this gives me the horizontal scroll bar.

How can I change this standard scroll -

[image]

To something like this -

[image]

I'm sure it could probably be done with javascript, but don't know how to implement.

Cheers...

Comment: sorry should have mentioned, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using [Jquery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html).
If it doesn't solve your issue on its own, maybe a combination of it with Jquery UI as in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll) will.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

You can customize scroll bar size and color.

(You have not specified and I am assuming this is for web browsers)

Comment: I was hoping to change more than the size and color. Maybe add scroll arrows on each side like in my 2nd image.

Comment: you should be able to do that by onclick of those button and changing the scroll position. See similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added/7303972#7303972

Comment: the scroll bar and those buttons are two different implementations

Comment: I will keep this in mind for other scroll options I may want in the future. Cheers...