# how to scroll IFrame without placing the mouse pointer on IE scrollbar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this asp.net page as below.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page" >
    <iframe id="iFrame1" style="width:100%" runat="server" 
    height="1100"  scrolling="yes"
    src="login.aspx"
     frameborder="0" align="left">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

To scroll the iframe,I have to put the mouse pointer over the IE scroll bar. I just want to place the mouse pointer over the iframe and scroll the page.Please advice. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added/7303972#7303972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution:

```
<div id="pane" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
   <iframe id="iFrame1" width="800" height="600" src="login.aspx" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#pane").hover(function()
{
  $("#pane").scrollTop(400).scrollLeft(400);
  return false;
});
</script>
```

For smoother scrolling you can use the jquery `animate` function.