# Automatically scrolling a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which contains a chat box. Whenever a new message arrives, it is appended to the box - and I want to automatically scroll the box to the bottom (to show the new message). How can I accomplish this?

```
<div  id="chatting" style="overflow: auto; background-color: #fff; border: solid 2px #dedede; width: 600px;  height: 500px; padding: 10px;">
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
  hello<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto-scroll to end of div when data is added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Do you want the page to be scrolled to the bottom when it loads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the `scrollTop` property of the chat window `div`. To scroll to the bottom of the div, set `scrollTop` equal to `scrollHeight`:

```
var chatWindow = document.getElementById('chating');
chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8Hd/

Alternatively, using jQuery:

```
var chatWindow = $("#chating");
chatWindow.scrollTop(chatWindow[0].scrollHeight);
```

You'll want to call this each time a chat message has been added to the div.