# Javascript Scroll is always top side in chatting

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, chat

;Hi all,

I try to do chat program.İf i write message , it goes under.
However,

if i write many messages , page stays top side , scroll is always top side.

How can i set scroll position to last message position ?

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
$messages = $("#messages");

chat.client.addMessage = function (frm, msg) {
$messages.append("<br /><b>" + frm + ":</b>" + msg);
}
$("#txtMsg").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
var input = $(this).val();
chat.server.sendMessage("@Session.SessionID", input);
$(this).val("");
var MessageData = {
frm: "@Session.SessionID",
msg: input
};
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/GetMessage",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(MessageData),
});
}
});
$.connection.hub.start();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>Your ID: @Session.SessionID</div>
<input type="text" id="txtMsg" />
<div id="messages">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at one of many entries in Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added

Comment: Check the indentation!