# How to disable my element auto-scroll briefly

Tags: html, autoscroll

I used the answer to this question to auto-scroll a combat log for my HTML5 game to the bottom:

[How to auto-scroll to end of div when data is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added/7303977#7303977)

If I want to briefly disable this while a person clicks to scroll up and view the log, how would I do so?

The Code I'm using is:

```
//autoscroll combat log

window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('log');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 500);
```

Best regards,
Cobwebs

Edit: the code above is connected to a simple span in a div:

```
<div>
    <span id='log'></span>
</div>
```

Stylized to have a scrollbar:

```
span#log {

    display: block;
    font-family: courier, sans;
    margin: auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:black;
    color: lime;
    text-align: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) returns an ID, with that ID you can use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) to stop it

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('log');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 500);
```

and then this

```
window.clearInterval(intervalID);
```

[small DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SGhm4/)

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  Is there a way to trigger it when the player clicks to scroll up?

Comment: @cobwebs you need to provide more information or small demo to how you are doing things