# How to set default position of overflow to the bottom of the div

Tags: php, jquery, chat

I am trying to make something like live chat. I want to set default position of displayed text on the bottom, like on facebook chat or all other chats. I mean I have the newest messages on the bottom of the div and the oldest on the top. When I open the chat, it shows me the oldest messages.
I am very thankful for all advices! 
Thank you!

There are CSS settings of chat pannel:

```
 #chat {
 position: absolute;
 top: 90px;
 bottom: 220px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: auto;
  color: #141855;
 }

 #chat_content {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: That's a great project. **What have you tried**?

Comment: @tadman I have tried some jquery functions which I've found here, on StackOverflow, but it didn't work for me...

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7303977

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a very helpful explanation. What's the specific problem? What was it supposed to do, and what did it do instead?

Comment: @SirajulHaq I am not good at jQuery, so could you please help me, how to delete that interval? Because that function works, but every 5sec it throws me back to the bottom, when I want to read older messages..

Comment: @tadman it should show me bottom of the div, like when I've already scrolled down, but it did nothing, I appeared on the top and had to scroll down for new messages

Comment: You just need to use this code var elem = document.getElementById('data');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight; and put whatever div id you have set to div in place of data.

Comment: @SirajulHaq it doesn't work then...
I've tried this:
`<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
});

</script>`, but it doesn't work neither...

Comment: You have to put it when you show that div, i mean if there is any click function is bind.

Comment: @SirajulHaq I am not sure if I understood you well.. Anyway, I've tried another way, how it could work, but it didn't again...
`window.setTimeout(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);`

Comment: @SirajulHaq oh, it works! I just had set the same time for re-load content and for scroll. I had to set bigger value to setTimeout. Thank you!