# AutoScrolling in javascript div

Tags: javascript, html

When i am using the above function in javascript div to auto scroll in chat box
but i am not able to scroll up to bottom.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 var elem = document.getElementById('chatlog');
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 10);
```

The chatlog is a div in my code and I have put above function to scroll the replies. Now I cannot scroll up.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: chatlog is div in my code and i have put above function to scroll the replies now i cannot scroll up

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added

Comment: Please make sure your chatlog element has height property set so that scrolltop can work

Comment: You have to clear interval on scroll up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logical mistake. In your code every 10 ms your script will scroll  div to bottom. There are many variants how to implement autoscroll behaviour. One of them use flag, which will set up by checkBox (autoscroll). If checkBox is selected script will scroll down, if deselected script will do nothing.

Something like:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 if (needAutoScroll) {
     var elem = document.getElementById('chatlog');
     elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
 }
}, 10);
```

Comment: It might also be clever to automatically check the box when you scroll to the bottom (if it wasn't previously unchecked manually), and automatically uncheck the box when you start scrolling up. This is more complicated logic though, so would take more explaining.

Comment: Yes, it is possible :-) Just question was: Now I cannot scroll up. So i provided one of simplest decision.

Comment: Of course. Just got inspired by your answer :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, so much. We can do awesome scrolls :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is  , since it is scrolling down to the bottom of the div every second , you are not able to scroll up. So on scroll up you have to clear the `setInterval` function.

You can try this in you `chatlog` div.

`<div id="chatlog" onscroll="myStopFunction()">`

```
function myStopFunction() {

if document.body.scrollTop <= 0 {
 console.log("scrolling down")
} else {
console.log("scrolling up");
 clearInterval(myVar);
}

}
```

Again on scroll down you can trigger the `setInterval` function.