# Page auto scroll into bottom

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I created a HTML page with several text paragraphs in it. I wanted it to **automatically** scroll bottom after opening the page. So I used following Javascript and it working fine. let say it is `page.html`

But then I needed it to display inside an iframe. Let say main page as `index.html`, `index.html` has iframe tag: `<iframe src="./page.html"></iframe>`

It also worked while loading inside the iframe within major browsers (chrome, firefox, IE, Opera) **but not in Apple's Safari mobile browser.**

I tested direct HTML page `page.html` with Safari mobile browser and it worked!

But after loaded same page inside an iframe in `index.html` it didn't work.

This is the Javascript I have used in `page.html`

```
<script language="javascript">
function autoScrolling() { window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); }
setInterval(autoScrolling, 1000); 
</script>
```

Please suggest me a code fix for Apple's Safari mobile browser

Comment: Consider loading the contents in iframe into the DIV instead. Your approach may lead to double scrolling. Also, iframe is NOT mobile friendly; avoid using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-scroll to end of div when data is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, example:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;">
     <iframe ...> ... </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I used it but it only does allowing scrolling on Safari mobile, problem is, after page opened, iframe src content should be automatically scrolled down into bottom.

Comment: @UdayaArunakantha try this `JS` code instead, `var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); myIframe.onload = function () {myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord);}`

Comment: I tried it, but not working in safari, here is the link: https://www.onlanka.com/mychat/temp/

Comment: I have no access to apple device, so I can not test the demo. try using `px` values instead of `%`. or try to scroll the iframe just a bit, e.g: 100px

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `-webkit-overflow-srolling: touch` on the parent of the iframe, and set a height for your iframe.

```
<style>
.parent-iframe {
   -webkit-overflow-srolling: touch;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
iframe {
  height: 100vh
}
</style>
<div class="parent-iframe">
 <iframe src="http://someurl.com ...>
</div>
```

Also if you have some `position: fixed` elements in your iframe they will not be fixed on ios safari. You can try this solution to avoid that:
https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix

Comment: I used it but it only does allowing scrolling on Safari mobile, problem is, after page opened, iframe src content should be automatically scrolled down into bottom.

Comment: did you put the script wich trigger the scroll on the iframe side?

Comment: try also to execute the script after window load. `window.addEventListener('load', { yourscript })`