# HTML span tag auto scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTMl file, I am trying to populate a span text zone with some voice-recognized text. I am struggling with one thing here:

Auto-scroll on the span zone:

```
<span id="final_span" class="final"></span>
```

Javascript code:

```
var final_span = document.getElementById("final_span");
finalDiv.innerHTML += '&nbsp' + data + '<p>';
finalDiv.scrollTop = finalDiv.scrollHeight;
```

The data inside the JavaScript keeps increasing, but when it exceeds the span limit, a scroll bar on the right appears because of the CSS code I wrote:   `overflow-y: scroll;` I would like to build it as auto-scroll until the bottom when text exceeds.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below, as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303948/how-to-auto-scroll-to-end-of-div-when-data-is-added) I have used `interval` to update `element's scrollTop to its scrollHeight every couple of seconds`. Below example I have used `textarea` to reproduce `data`.

```js
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("input", function(){
  document.getElementById('final_span').innerHTML += `&nbsp ${this.value}`;
});


window.setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('final_span').scrollTop = document.getElementById('final_span').scrollHeight;
}, 100);
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>  
<span id="final_span" class="final" style="display:block; height:100px; overflow-y: scroll;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could think of was to increase the scrolling of the text container with a function called with an event I use 'keyup' but when your program work with voice you can use change. the other function only display the input value on the div.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#text-field');
const div = document.querySelector('#text-display');

function pageScroll() {
        div.scrollBy(0,300);
}
function writeLines(){
   div.innerHTML = input.value;
   pageScroll();
}

input.addEventListener('keyup',writeLines);
```

```html
<input id="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Escribe aqui"/>
<div id="text-display" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 200px"></div>
```