# How DIV scrolls in chat script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat

I coded for a chat script and all the issue is with scrolling DIV layer. I downloaded few chat scripts and found the below after careful observation.

When ever a new line of chat is added, scroll bar doesn't scrolls down **after chat line is added.** Its **adding to the bottom of the DIV layer** as the scroll doesn't make any kind of disturbance while making it.

What I did:

Before I used javascript to scroll down for every fixed interval. Doing this I am unable to manually scroll up to view past lines(due to interval refresh scroll bar moves to set position). Later I coded for a javascript that can scrolls down `OnClientClick` but doing this I can only able to scroll down `Chat sender side` but it cannot scroll down at `Chat receiver side` when a new chat line is added.

I downloaded many chat scripts and checked how this particular issue is managed but I couldn't find any solution for it. I fairly guess that its the work of jQuery (not sure) can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

I am sorry if you failed to understand my issue as I am unable to explain it in more detailed than as above. However I can give you more information on request.

Languages I am using are ASP.NET, AJAX update panels, timer ticks for updating div with new values, javascripts are till now used only to scroll down the element.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666649/auto-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chat 'screen' should look like this:

```
<div id="chat">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- chat messages go here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Put overflow-y: auto on the chat, but leave the wrapper as it is. Create on function that runs at an interval and add or removes a class "atBottom" to chat 'screen' based on value returned by $('#chat').scrollTop() method.

```
    monitor = function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
            height = $this.height(),
            maxScroll = wrap.height() - height,
            top = $this.scrollTop();
        if (maxScroll === top) {
            $this.addClass('atBottom');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('atBottom');
        }
    }
    window.setInterval(function() {
        monitor.call($('#chat').get(0));
    }, 350);
```

Then you need to bind an event 'addMessage' that works like so:

```
    $('#chat').bind('addMessage', function(e, message) {
        var $this = $(this),
            // store whether it's at the bottom before appending the message
            scroll = $this.hasClass('atBottom');
        // then append the message
        $this.find('.wrapper').append(message);
        if (scroll) {
            // measure the new maxScroll and scroll to it.
            var wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
                height = $this.height(),
                maxScroll = wrap.height() - height
            $this.scrollTop(maxScroll);
        }
    })
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#chat').trigger('addMessage', 'asdgagasdg<br/>');
    });
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WVLE2/

Comment: Thanks dude, this worked for me. Thanks again. You cleared my several months of doubt.

Comment: But dude, is there a way to implement same using javascripts?

Comment: You mean without using jQuery?

Comment: Yes! without using jQuery! it is possible? can I implement the same?

Comment: I am waiting for your answer.!

Comment: Yes, it is possible (anything done is jQuery is possible in Javascript, as jQuery is a subset of JavaScript, written in JavaScript). However, certain jQuery capabilities -- event handling, the jQuery.scrollTop() and jQuery.trigger() methods, etc. -- make it much easier to use jQuery for this type of effect.

Comment: Can you describe how it does not work properly? It works for me.