# scroll to the bottom when a new message has been added

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var elementshoku = document.getElementById("1on1shoku");
    var lastHeightshoku = elementshoku.scrollHeight;
    function detectChangeshoku(){
        var currentHeightshoku = elementshoku.scrollHeight;
        if(lastHeightshoku != currentHeightshoku){
    alert("xxx");
    elementshoku.scrollTop = currentHeightshoku;
    lastHeightshoku = currentHeightshoku;
        }
    }
    var mesazhet_shoku = setInterval(detectChangeshoku, 200); 
</script>
```

I am making a chat and I would like to scroll the div to the bottom when a user writes a message. I am using that function, but it is not working. I did put the `alert();` function to check if the function above works or not. I have tried many ways, but none of them works. Any idea why it does not work?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I see that my question was not clear enough. I am making a chat and I want the div to Auto-scroll to the bottom if there is written e new message. In this answer, it is said to do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666680/1932887 but it does not work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
jqEl.scrollTop(jqEl.scrollHeight());
```

Using DOM:

```
oEl.scrollTop = oEl.scrollHeight;
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQePe/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't request the `getElementById("1on1shoku")` and read it's `scrollHeight` before it has been rendered. Put the first lines in the onload like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elementshoku, lastHeightshoku;
window.onload=function() {
    elementshoku = document.getElementById("1on1shoku");
    lastHeightshoku = elementshoku.scrollHeight;
}
function detectChangeshoku(){
    var currentHeightshoku = elementshoku.scrollHeight;
    if(lastHeightshoku != currentHeightshoku){
        elementshoku.scrollTop = currentHeightshoku;
        lastHeightshoku = currentHeightshoku;
    }
}
var mesazhet_shoku = setInterval(detectChangeshoku, 200);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery. It helps your code cleaner and easier to understand for future maintenance. By using jQuery you can do it by:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#1on1shoku").scrollTop() }, 1000);
});
```