# Scroll to the bottom of the content in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div which is a chat window. As people send messages and they are appended to the end of the content I want the content to scroll to the bottom (so the latest chat message is visible).

```
<div id="chat">

</div><!--chat end-->
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean at the bottom?  The scrollbar should be on one sides of the div from top to bottom...

Comment: I mean , keep it scrolled down

Comment: On second thoughts... maybe you should take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/270628/558021

Comment: Just append the Content to the div and try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the CSS value `scrollTop` to the content height (or `scrollHeight`) of the container.

Here is the example code and I've used it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHx2Z/

```
// get the new height of the chat window
var height = $('#chat_window')[0].scrollHeight;
$('#chat_window').animate({scrollTop:height}, 1000); // you could use .css() instead if you don't want it to animate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.scrollTop().

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Hope it helps.