# How keep scroll bar in bottom in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, scroll, scrollbar

I have many tabs and when click any tab, a vertical scrolling div is shown. Like facebook messages page: When click to any User's name. Dialog seems and scroll bar **is on the bottom of div by default**.

Here is tabs:

```
<ul class="companies">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <li id='company_@(item.Id)' data-id='@item.Id' >
           <a>@item.Name</a>
       </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And content:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <div id="scrollingDiv"  class="scrollingDiv"> @item.News </div>
}
```

And CSS:

```
.scrollingDiv {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I want to keep scroll bar on the bottom when click any tab. (To see always last news). Also current div. I checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) questions. But not worked in my application. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think the $("#mydiv").scrollTop($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight); thing should work for you. How do you know you implemented this code correctly?

Comment: I checked that code by class name, not by id.
$(".scrollingDiv").scrollTop($(".scrollingDiv")[0].scrollHeight);
  Nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `scrollTop()` function might be just what you need. See http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 4):

With JavaScript, you can do something like

```
var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

if(d.scrollHeight > d.clientHeight) {
  d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight;
}
```

and execute this logic every time you add content to the div or when you want the scrollable container to scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using below code

```
$('.full-area').scrollTop($('.full-area')[0].scrollHeight);
```