# Javascript scroll to bottom doesn't always scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an Iframe which reloads itself every 5 seconds. It makes use of javascript to automaticly scroll to the bottom because it has too much content to display in one go, but sometimes after a refresh the scroll bar doesn't go down all the way. Leaving me scrolling it down myself.

I really don't know what it is. Maybe one of you has a better peice of Javascript suited for this.

Javascript:

```
<script>
var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
</script>
```

The HTML div:

```
<div id="chat" class="scroll">
*Content going on for 150 lines...*
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to put it inside window.onload, like this: `window.onload = function(){//code here}`..

Comment: [This `scrollTop` assignment should work](http://jsfiddle.net/D8MTy/), error is probably in some surrounding code. You should add that to the question, as it is relevant

Comment: try to put it inside window.onload, like this: window.onload = function(){//code here}.. –  user3003216 THIS WORKED! please put it into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could conceivably create a placeholder div at the bottom of your page, and use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) to scroll to the bottom of it. This would ensure that you always scroll to that div, rather than what the query perceives as the bottom of the page.