# how to scroll bottom of div using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a div in which I added element .I want to scroll to bottom of the div whenever element added in div.I know how to do in in jquery .But I did not know how to scroll using angular js
I know using jquery
[Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

testCaseContainer is id of div .

```
var elem = document.getElementById('testCaseContainer'); // just to
                                                                    // scroll down
                                                                    // the line
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

I want to know how it is possible using angular ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8tCL8Szc3h3FatFLycG?p=preview

I added css in div container so that it scroll .

```
.heightClass{
  height:100px;
  overflow :auto;
}
```

how to move focus below when item is added ..please post your answer..

Answer (score 19):

You could create your own scroll directive that watches a collection, and when it changes, sets the scroll position:

```
app.directive('scroll', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watchCollection(attr.scroll, function(newVal) {
        $timeout(function() {
         element[0].scrollTop = element[0].scrollHeight;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="heightClass" scroll="studentDetail">
```

Note: $timeout is needed to ensure that the scroll position is set after the view is rendered.

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGWS8S0cX7qxZBmtkwHT?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you especially for the $timeout tip!

Comment: what is studentDetail ?