# How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<table>` setup to display a set of data that is generated via PHP from a MySQL Database. The `<table>` is located inside a `<div>` with a  max-height CSS property. Sometimes the information exceeds the max-height, and I would like to scroll to the bottom of the `<table>`.

I am currently using the bellow jQuery, but it only scrolls down to the middle of the `<div>`.

```
var mydiv = $('#mes');
mydiv.scrollTop(mydiv.prop('scrollHeight'));
```

Thank you very much, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should have your jquery in a `$(document).ready(function () {});`  Also, please see [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2664878/3033053)

Comment: The actual HTML would be useful in debugging this issue.

Comment: Sounds more like you need `overflow: scroll` on the containing div.

Comment: I think it's be useful if create a JSFiddle.