# Automatically scroll to bottom of div

Tags: javascript, html

On my webpage the sql results are returned in a div where the maximum width and height has been defined and the overflow has been set to scroll. When someone visits the page I would like the default scroll position to be at the bottom. I have done a lot of research and the best solution I could find without using jQuery fails to work ([Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)). Therefore I am wondering if anybody can explain where my error is or an alternate solution without using jQuery.

**My Code**

```
<html>
<style>
#test{
max-height: 150px;
max-width: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
background: #50a8ff;    
}
</style>    
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var objDiv = document.getElementById("test");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"><h4>BIG TEXT</h4><h4>BIG TEXT</h4><h4>BIG TEXT</h4><h4>BIG TEXT</h4>
<h4>BIG TEXT</h4><h4>BIG TEXT</h4><h4>BIG TEXT</h4></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the problem.

**Potential Causes**

As the SQL data is fetched once the page has loaded, therefore would the scroll height be set before the div is filled, would setting a delay solve this problem? Although in this simple example I have the same problem even though the data is not being loaded from an SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

the scrollHeight method is not always correct sometimes it gives unexpected values
try this

1.add a div inside your overflow div

```
 <div class="container which has overflow">
   <div class="inner div with no padding"> // note that this div must not have any padding margins are fine
       MY CONTENT
   </div>
 </div>
```

2.JS code with jquery(I dont know about non-jquery)

```
 var div = $(".container"); // the div which has the overflow
 var div_inner = $(".container_inner"); //the div inside the overflow one
 var a = div_inner.outerHeight();//get the height of the inner div
 div.scrollTop(a);  // make the overflow fiv scroll to the bottom
```