# how to scroll to bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to scroll to the bottom of the div `content-main`, so that the button `Button` is displayed at the `bottom of the window`. I tried the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-main">
    dynamic content dynamic content.....  
    <button>Button </button>
    </div>
    <div class ="footer"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var mainContentHeight = $(".content-main").height();
    var footerHeight = $(".content-footer").height();
    window.scrollTo(0, mainContentHeight - footerHeight);
</script>
```

This works differently, when I test it in two monitors with different size. How to display the button at the bottom of the window?

Comment: Are you wanting the button to automatically be displayed at the bottom of the window and then on scroll keep its place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 0):

Instead binding scrollTo to the window object, bind it to the element you want to scroll:

```js
var container =  $('.container')[0];
var contentMain = $('.content-main')[0];
var mainContentHeight = $(".content-main").height();
var footerHeight = $(".content-footer").height();
 
container.scrollTo(0, mainContentHeight - footerHeight);
```

```css
 .container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
 }
.content-main {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1000px;
}
.content-footer {
  height: 50px;
}
button {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-main">
    dynamic content dynamic content.....  
    <button>Button </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. But the button is not displayed at the buttom

Comment: I tried this example. the button is displayed at different vertical places with different screens sizes