# Auto Scroll Down with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like you to help me make a Javascript code with autoscroll down in one particular div in one page, and while it scrolls down i want to make one procedure.

Im new in javascript but i know these things to help you out

```
<div class="uiScrollableAreaWrap scrollable" data-reactid=".c6.0">
```

This is the div of the box that is scrollable.

Could you give me an example of how can i make a javascript code
to take this class and scroll down until the end of the Wrap??

Update one.

http://screencast.com/t/8WNIFZB8rYG

Check out this photo to see all the divs of the box that i want to scroll down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[Relevant SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/270628)**

Just for your case:

This will scroll down to bottom of the div

```
var objDiv = document.querySelector("._5tee .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dizoxu/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Update:

based on your screenshot, Assuming that you want to scroll the `ul` list to the bottom.

```
var ulList= document.querySelector("._5tee .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
ulList.scrollTop = ulList.scrollHeight;
```

In case you want it for other div, use this pattern

```
.uiScrollableAreaWrap.scrollable yourdivselector
```

Comment: It's quite clear that you slightly adapted code from [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/270628). Please vote to close instead.

Comment: This scrolls the main page... maybe i copied the wrong div, wait to edit it

Comment: Added link to that page as well @nicael

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios change the selector inside document.querySelector to match your div element.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, updated @KwnstantinosNatsios

Comment: ` var objDiv = document.querySelector("._5tee .uiScrollableAreaWrap");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight; `

this works for my case, but i want to make it in a loop cause when i put this code it only does one scroll down and after is loading more contents in the box and then i have to do it again so it can scroll down with the new contents.
thanks anyway its a big step. copy paste the code to your answer so i can approve it since you helped me with the main code :)