# Why when scrolling element upwards does the y / top position number not change here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I'm working on building a infinite scroll feature in an Angular app. Building 1 step at a time, currently I'm at the part where I've attached a scroll eventListener to the `#tags-col` or `tagsCol`.

**plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7OnKAGvVNXWLwN5fZqJu?p=preview**

I have code that is suppose to return the top `y` value of tagsCol, however the number never updates with the logs as you scroll the element up, it stays stuck at `118.8125`.

How would you get the moving y value of the `tagsCol`? Or better yet, detect when the bottom / last element inside of the `tagsCol` panel is visible?

```
function getOffset(el) {
    el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: el.top + window.scrollY
    }
}

var scrollingElement =  function(event) {
    console.log(tagsCol);
    var yPos = getOffset(tagsCol).top
    console.log(yPos);
};

document.getElementById('tags-col').addEventListener('scroll', scrollingElement);
```

[image]

Comment: You can try and compare the elements `offsetTop` towards `window.pageYOffset` once you scroll. The elements position itself remains the same within the body even if you scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this solution might work for you.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("tags-col");
var offsetTop = el.offsetTop;

function callback() {
    if (offsetTop < window.pageYOffset) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", callback, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onscroll", callback);
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I get I need to do some kind of check, but still don't know how to get the correct value that is actually moving.

Comment: I found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) maybe it helps you?

Comment: Or [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) maybe?

Comment: Ah yeah that was it! `.scrollTop` Now I see the value changing... hmmm, next step put in an check to see when a certain point has been crossed, and actually next step is determine what that point should be.