# How to scroll down to bottom child div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following div structure.

```
<div id="conversation" class="list-view">
   <div class="conv">
       <div class="msg">Hi 1</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 2</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 3</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 4</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 5</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 6</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 7</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 8</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 9</div>
       <div class="msg">Hi 10</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now when i add on ajax submit button new div `<div class="msg">Hi 11</div>` added at the end of `<div class="conv">`. i want to scroll down to the bottom new added div.

i have used following but it doesn't work.

```
$('.conv ').animate({scrollTop: $('.conv')[0].scrollHeight}, 'slow');
$('.conv').scrollTop($('.conv')[0].scrollHeight);
```

How to scroll down to bottom child div. Position of parent div is fixed.

Comment: you need to add the css for the conv div

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: @Jazz, I meant add your current css for the conv div to the question. I was wanting to see if you had set a height on it

Comment: yes i have added `.conv{
    max-height:401px;
    overflow:auto;
}` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to fix the height of `.conv` if you want to scroll that. Else, use scroll on the body.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/775/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.conv ').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.conv .msg:last-child').position().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
.conv {
    max-height:100px; //for demo
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it scroll to last element but after scrolling again focus to the top div. and is possible to not to div `max-height`?

Comment: You'll need to have a height in order to scroll that div. Without the height, scrollbar will not appear and hence no scrolling will happen. So, you will have to set some height on that div. You can scroll back to the top of the div by again following the same login in the callback function of animate.

Comment: Yes. but it is first scroll to bottom and then again to first. i only want to scroll down to bottom.

Comment: Then instead of the :last-child in the selector, add the index of the newly added element. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/778/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as:

```
$('.conv').animate({scrollTop: $('.conv div.msg:last').offset().top});
```

For the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/776/

Comment: I would use `position` rather than `offset`

Comment: You can use that as the .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent whereas the offset() method retrieves the current position relative to the document.

Comment: @sahilgupta, it is the offset parent that OP is wanting to scroll - not the document