# how do why make scroll bar at the bottom every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**how do why make scroll bar at the bottom every time when loading
pages. tell me immediately**

This is javascript not working. please help me

```
#student_name{
    height:315px;
 }     
 <div id = "student_name">abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br></div>

 var objDiv = document.getElementById("student_name");
 objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you mean. Do you want to scroll to the bottom of the div when the page loads? Also, saying "tell me immediately" will not get you faster answers - probably the reverse.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Comment: Make sure the JS is executed when the DOM is ready, for instance by using `onload`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is two things first in css:

```
#student_name{ height:100px; overflow:auto;}
```

add a overflow property.

and in the markup you should not add spaces with the attributes `id = "student_name"`, it should be:

```
id="student_name"
```

and js code is actually working.

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("student_name");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
#student_name{ height:100px; overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="student_name">abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br>abc<br></div>
```