# Scroll to bottom of div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a window using html and javascript to display display log messages generated by my website.  I want to set it up so that when the user opens the log window it auto scrolls to the bottom of the log messages.  I've gotten it so that the log messages display correctly, but I am having trouble getting the auto scroll to work.

My html/javascript looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h4 class="text-center">Log Messages</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="content" id="logtext">
        <font face="courier">
          <span id="show" class='value'></span>
        </font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function saveLogs(data){
      sessionStorage.setItem("logs",data.message);
    }
      $(document).ready(
        function() {
          setInterval(function() {
            Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(saveLogs);
            var logs = sessionStorage.getItem("logs");
            document.querySelector('.content .value').innerText = logs;
            //I tried doing this and nothing happened.
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("logtext");
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
          }, 1000);
        });
  </script>
</div>        
</body>
```

The call to `dajaxice` is just basically grabbing the last n lines of a log file that I have and then sending them to the js function I defined as `saveLogs()`.

I've tried using some of the solutions given in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) but haven't had any luck getting them to work.

**EDIT**
I tried setting it up like this:

```
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="content" id="logtext">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('bottomspan').scrollIntoView();
        </script>
        <font face="courier">
          <span id="show" class='value'>
          </span>
          <div id='bottomspan'></div> 
        </font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function saveLogs(data){
      sessionStorage.setItem("logs",data.message);
    }
      $(document).ready(
        // document.getElementById('bottomspan').scrollIntoView();
        function() {
          setInterval(function() {
            Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(saveLogs);
            var logs = sessionStorage.getItem("logs");
            document.querySelector('.content .value').innerText = logs;
            var el = document.getElementById('bottomspan')
            el.scrollIntoView();
            var height = el.style.clientHeight
            window.scrollBy(0, height);
          },700);
        });
  </script>
```

This worked except every time the page refreshes with new messages it goes back to the bottom; this makes it hard to view older messages at the top.  Is there a way to have it start at the bottom of the div but not force the user back down if they are looking at messages near the top?

Comment: Are you certain `#logtext` is the element that is scroll-able?

Answer (score 5):

Here Try:

```
document.getElementById('logtext').scrollIntoView();
```

**EDIT**

```
document.getElementById('bottomspan').scrollIntoView();

<font face="courier">
      <span id="show" class='value'> content.... 
           <span id='bottomspan'></span>
       </span>
</font>
```

**EDIT**

```
var el = document.getElementById('logtext')
el.scrollIntoView();
var height = el.style.clientHeight
window.scrollBy(0, height - window.innerHeight);
```

**Edit to answer Edit**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function saveLogs(data){
      sessionStorage.setItem("logs",data.message);
    }
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(saveLogs);
        var logs = sessionStorage.getItem("logs");
        document.querySelector('.content .value').innerText = 
      },700);

        var el = document.getElementById('bottomspan')
        el.scrollIntoView();
        var height = el.style.clientHeight
        window.scrollBy(0, height);
    });
```

Comment: Its also good because it's supported by all major browsers and doesn't require any additional libraries like jQuery

Comment: I tried adding this under `document.querySelector('.content .value').innerText = logs;` but causes the scrolling to start at the top of the div every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: is your span above or below the content or is the content in the span?

Comment: The content is in the span, but I tried changing it to `document.getElementById('show').scrollIntoView();` and it produced the same results.

Comment: put an element in the span below the content and scroll to that

Comment: Doing that over wrote all of my log messages.

Comment: The new ddit should scroll the top into view and then it will get offset by the height of the element

Comment: yeah thats because you set the interval just remove that from there or do you need it to happen after the ajax call succeeds please remember to mark your question as resolved once compete :0

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var $objDiv = $("#logtext");
$objDiv.scrollTop( $objDiv.height() );
```

Your script works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/b1tf63yd/1/

Comment: Nothing happened when I added these lines.

Comment: This solution requires JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Just focus on the element to make the element visible.

```
<span id="feed_item" />

document.getElementById("feed_item").focus();
```