# How to scroll down a specific div of page having pagination using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to scroll down page and get the last element of that section/div.
i have executed the code:

---

```
Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable)element).getCoordinates();
    coordinate.inViewPort();
```

and also tried with

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
```

But it is scrolling the entire page instead of scrolling the specific section
[image]

And also the page has pagination

Comment: Can you fire up seleniumIDE and see what actiosn are generated? It would save time - you can then export in your required format

Comment: In IDE nothing is getting recorded if performing action of scroll down, because i think if any element will be clickable only that actions will be recorded, but here nothing clickable only i have to scroll down

Comment: You will have to use javascript for this. Get the element using document.getel... and use the scrollTop and pass the pixels to it.  var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    elmnt.scrollTop = 100;

Comment: i have tried this, but this is showing compilation error, for var and document

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find the element you're trying to scroll to:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_here")); //or anything else used to identify the element
```

Afterwards, you can execute JS using `JavascriptExecutor` to bring the element into view using `scrollIntoView()` :

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried will scroll the window scroll bar, try something like below

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;  
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",dr.findElement(By...));
```

Specify the locator of the element which you are trying to find by scrolling down.

arguments[0]

Edit:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;  
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop(arguments[0].scrollHeight);",dr.findElement(By...));
```

Comment: i just want to scroll down the page till the last element comes because last element is not a constant it will be changed every time and also numbers will increase, and if am trying this its not getting the element as pagination is also there in the section.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Comment: var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight; here i have to mention the id of div how can i get it

Comment: Not necessiraly the div id, it is the elemnet inside which your scroll bar is present. It can be span, table, frame what ever it is.