# Scrollable DIV, I want to create an animation that scrolls to the bottom of the div on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV that has an overflow-y set to scroll.

```
.scrolling-div {
width: 85%;
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Assuming that I have a bunch of content inside this div, I want it to scroll all the way to the bottom of the div on pageload. I actually want to see the animation of the scroll (so the div would start at the top, but then I want to see it scroll to the bottom).

How do I create this with either Javascript, Jquery, or just pure CSS? I also want to be able to control the speed of the scroll animation.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('.scrolling-div').animate({ 
   scrollTop: $('.scrolling-div').prop('scrollHeight')
}, 1000);
```

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qmz4abgk/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var wtf    = $('#scroll');
  var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
  wtf.scrollTop(height);
});

#scroll {
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">
```

Comment: Is this answer ok for you?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Actually, disregard my last comment. It is working now, but it doesn't allow me to control speed.