# React scrollTop not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a react component with a scrollable div I'm trying to get the div to scroll to the bottom after it mounts:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var scrollNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.scrollElement);
    scrollNode.scrollTop = scrollNode.scrollHeight;
}
```

the scrollNode exists and reflects the correct div however, the value of scrollTop is never changed (it remains 0 even if i set it to some arbitrary number) and the scroll doesn't occur.

UPDATE:
Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/johnryan1/pen/BWoeKQ

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas i'm trying to get the div to scroll to the bottom on mount (i updated the question for clarity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: Try using the solution in the post above.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas yea that doesn't work either, basically there is no value of scrollTop that does anything, if i say scrollTop = 999 then inspect scrollTop it is still 0, I thought this might be something particular to do with react

Comment: Can you create a plunker / codepen?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas added a codepen https://codepen.io/johnryan1/pen/BWoeKQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a height to your container in your css. For example

```
.list
   height: 100px
```