# How to make a Div scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i have a textbox and a button. After pressing the add button to the table inside a div.
I want the div to scroll to the bottom of the page when `max-height:100px;` exceeded`overflow-y:auto;`  `addbarcode();` method is a ajax post which will call a jquery `dataTable method`to populate data on the server side.

**try 1**

```
var element = document.getElementById("divcontent");

        element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

**try 2**

```
 var element = document.getElementById("divcontent");
                $('#divcontent').scrollTo(element.get(0).scrollHeight);
```

**try 3**

```
 var objDiv = document.getElementById("divcontent");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

above attempts all doesnt work.

**edit**

```
<div class="row" id="divcontent" style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:auto">

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="codelist">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    SN
                </th>
                <th>
                    Serial Number
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scanner").on('keyup paste', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            var artno = $(this).val();
            if (artno.length == 32 && ) {
                addbarcode();
                $(this).val("");

            } else {
                $(this).val("");
            }
            var element = document.getElementById("divcontent");

            element.scrollIntoView(false);
        }


    });

})
```

**final working code**
added animate to allow smooth scrolling . also added timer as ajax code run faster than html render .so setting a little delay allows the javascript to capture full height.

```
  function divscrolldown() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#divcontent').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#divcontent").offset().top
        }, 500);

    }, 200);
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your code.

Comment: please try with a div and some css

Comment: sorry for replying late. attached my codes

Comment: solved. i am adding the code at the wrong button event all the while.sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

If `false`, the bottom of the element will be aligned to the bottom of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor.

MDN: [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: thank you, Really learned. i have read more 10 question in Stack Overflow, this is the only one that use scrollintoview. thank you very much.  You are so genius.

Comment: Perfect.  Spent an hour trying all other solutions.  This was the only one that worked for my div!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('#scroll').scrollTop(1000000);
```

There's more answers here: [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)