# How do I scroll to an element which is present inside an overflow div which itself is inside an an overflow container?

Tags: javascript

Everytime I add a new element the page should scroll to the bottom of the inner div (having id = content). Right now scrollTo scrolls to the top of the outer div aka container

https://jsfiddle.net/fLd7mxpq/

```
// css
    .container{
      background: #eee;
      height: 800px;
    }
    .inner-div{
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 100px;
      background: #aaa;
    }
<script>
function addItem() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += "<p>Some new Data</p>";
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-div" id="content">
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <p>
  Some random data
  </p>
  <button onclick="addItem()">
  Add Item
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't 0,0 just the top left? also, does this not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Comment: @Matthias Is correct.  That answer in the linked question will solve your issue.  For completeness sake, here is your code using a similar scheme: https://jsfiddle.net/7de36k19/

Comment: No, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Etherealm can you explain?  Are you trying to scroll the inner div or the outer div?

Comment: I'm trying to scroll the inner div to bottom. The height of outer div doesn't change if content is added to inner div. Right now when I try the above mentioned code, the outer div gets scrolled.

Comment: In the linked fiddle from my comment, it scrolls `.inner-div`, not `.container` nor window.  Is that not correct?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7de36k19/2/
Updated the jsfiddle. Now clicking add button should scroll to the new item added.