# Scroll action in PureScript Halogen

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm using purescript-halogen, and I want to scroll to bottom of div when the child component's message were caught.
However, it seems not present that scroll action control in Halogen.
So, how can I
[Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270612/8157957)

One solution I think is that call other, not Halogen, process from Main when the event caught.
I'm not sure that this solution is not bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the scroll position is just done through using the normal DOM functionality, targeting the rendered node.

To do this, you'll need to add a [`ref`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-halogen/2.1.0/docs/Halogen.HTML.Properties#v:ref) property in the HTML DSL to the node you want to scroll:

```
-- Define this in the same module as / in the `where` for a component
containerRef ∷ H.RefLabel
containerRef = H.RefLabel "container"

-- Use it with the `ref` property like so:
render =
  HH.div
    [ HP.ref containerRef ]
    [ someContent ]
```

And then in the `eval` for the component you can get hold of the actual DOM element created, using [`getHTMLElementRef`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-halogen/2.1.0/docs/Halogen.Query#v:getHTMLElementRef), and then update the scroll position on that:

```
eval (ScrollToBottom next) = do
  ref ← H.getHTMLElementRef containerRef
  for_ ref \el → H.liftEff do
    scrollHeight ← DOM.scrollHeight el
    offsetHeight ← DOM.offsetHeight el
    let maxScroll ← scrollHeight - offsetHeight 
    DOM.setScrollTop maxScroll el
  pure next
```

The snippets here are modified from some [real world code](https://github.com/slamdata/slamdata/blob/6095ee2c6367072d475104d47454d2d6966d7490/src/SlamData/Workspace/MillerColumns/Component.purs) that does something similar, so should do the trick!

Comment: It means a lot to me. 
Now my code works!
`eval Scroll
    ref <- H.getHTMLElementRef streamRef
        for_ ref \el -> H.liftEff do
            scrollHeight <- scrollHeight $ htmlElementToElement el
            offsetHeight <- offsetHeight el
            setScrollTop (scrollHeight - offsetHeight) $ htmlElementToElement et
    pure next`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543329/1685973, but I had a hard time finding the different imports:

```
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import DOM.HTML.Types (htmlElementToElement)
import DOM.Node.Element (scrollHeight, setScrollTop)
import DOM.HTML.HTMLElement (offsetHeight)

...

-- Define this in the same module as / in the `where` for a component
containerRef ∷ H.RefLabel
containerRef = H.RefLabel "container"

-- Use it with the `ref` property like so:
render =
  HH.div
    [ HP.ref containerRef ]
    [ someContent ]

...

eval (ScrollToBottom next) = do
  ref <- H.getHTMLElementRef containerRef
  for_ ref $ \el -> H.liftEff $ do
    let hel = htmlElementToElement el
    sh <- scrollHeight hel
    oh <- offsetHeight el
    let maxScroll = sh - oh
    setScrollTop maxScroll hel
  pure next
```

Comment: The API has changed a bit - now `htmlElementToElement` is just `toElement` from `Web.HTML.HTMLElement`. The `scroll*` functions are now also in `Web.DOM`. The code still works, though.