# To Reset scroll position to newly added element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In a container elements will be added and sorted dynamically. on clcik of add button i will add a new element to list.
i want to set the scroll position to recently added element. Please help me out on this.

```html
<div ng-repeat="items in listItems | orderby" style="height:500px;overflow-y:auto"> 
 <p id="scrollPosition{{items}}"> {{items}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see some JS code? Where you add the new item.

Comment: I assume ur new item will be at the bottom of the div. You can then just scroll to bottom using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/270628/507203

Comment: Since i am sorting the list, once i add the element i will be sorted accordingly. so i need to point to particular position

Comment: We need to see how you add the new element. To know how you can get the element in the DOM and then use parent element [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @user123, please use snippets only if you have a working code, else just format the code using `` in the question, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. i found the solution for the above issue using angular anchor scroll. adding the below two lines in add() function solves my issue.                                                             $location.hash('scrollPosition'+$scope.item);
$anchorScroll();

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new element just give it a unique ID as well and then simply use this javascript

```
location.href = "#";
location.href = "#myDiv";
```

Answer (score 1):

**This one will definitely solve your problem. I have created this methods for myself.**

Please note that this is made according to datatables scrolling. you need to update classes like '.dataTables_scrollBody' according to your code.

```
var scrollPosition =0;
function saveScrollPosition ( container ) {
    if ( $( container ) != undefined && $( container ).find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ) != undefined ) {
        scrollPosition = $( container ).find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ).scrollTop();
    } else {
        scrollPosition = 0;
    }

}

function setScrollPosition ( container ) {
    if ( $( container ) != undefined && $( container ).find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ) != undefined ) {
        $( container ).find( '.dataTables_scrollBody' ).scrollTop( scrollPosition );
    } else {
        scrollPosition = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery animate function with `$("div#YourContentDiv p:last-child").offset()`

Also There is an angular animate example in Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yz1EHB8ad3C59N6PzdCD?p=preview:

```js
$("body, html").animate({ 
      scrollTop: $("div#YourContentDiv p:last-child").offset().top 
 }, 600);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="YourContentDiv">
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p>new text</p>
  <p style="color:red">new line</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="items in listItems | orderby" style="height:500px;overflow-y:auto"> 
<p id="scrollPosition{{items}}"> {{items}}</p>
```

//Controller

```js
  $scope.add = function(item){

 $location.hash('scrollPosition'+item);
  $anchorScroll();
}
```

The above Angular anchor scroll resolves my issue.