# how to set scrollbar to the bottom of a chat system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a chat example

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/vrzGb

and I want to scroll to the bottom with:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

But I need it for the class `.chat_area`. How can I do that?

```
 $('.chat_area').scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: ok thnx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jquery :

```
$(".chat_area").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
```