# Scroll to end of page after load ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, load

```
function chat (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_motor.php",cache: false,success: function(html){
            $("#chat").html(html);
        },
    });
}
setInterval (chat, 1000);
```

I want scroll to end of page after load `chat_motor.php`
how can i scroll to down after run this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: Did my answer below work for you? @amir ntm

Comment: yea Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```