# Unable to scroll a split screen of a webpage

Tags: vba, excel, scroll, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba to scrape some items from a webpage. By default, there are 4/5 items visible when I open that page. However, the webpage displays it's rest of the items when it is made to scroll downward. If it were not for split screen, I could have handled it using `.parentWindow.scrollBy`. As I do not have any idea how to scroll any partial screen of a webpage, I get stuck. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Link to the webpage: [Page_Link](https://www.quintoandar.com.br/alugar/imovel/sao-paulo-sp-brasil/1-vagas/de-20-a-75-m2/de-500-a-4400-reais/apartamento)

This is what I have written so far:

```
Sub Get_Result()
    Const URL As String = "replace with above link"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim storage As Object, posts As Object, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    For i = 1 To 5
        Set storage = html.getElementsByClassName("sc-jqCOkK gkztbk")
        html.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 100
        'SendKeys "{end}"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:003")
    Next i

    For Each posts In storage
            row = row + 1: Cells(row + 1, 1) = posts.querySelector("[id='app.components.HouseCard.rentLine']").innerText
    Next posts
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Btw, this is how that split window look like:
[image]

Post script: I'm only after any solution regarding scrolling a split screen like it is visible above.

Comment: Find the scroll-able container and sets `scrollTop` to a max int32. In your case: `html.querySelector("#app [style*=scroll]").scrollTop = &h7fffffff`

Comment: This CodeReview [Handling lazy-loading webpages using vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/handling-lazy-loading-webpages-using-vba/183242#183242) may help you. You need to find the class name of the posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the scrolling of the left window use the `div` with class name `sc-iqzUVk gZZIKO` and set [scrollTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms534618(v=vs.94)) to some value, e.g. use `scrollHeight` to [scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) like this `leftWindowDiv.scrollTop = leftWindowDiv.scrollHeight`.

*Complete example:*

```
Dim leftWindowColl As IHTMLElementCollection
Set leftWindowColl = html.getElementsByClassName("sc-iqzUVk gZZIKO")

If leftWindowColl.Length > 0 Then
    Dim leftWindowDiv As HTMLDivElement
    Set leftWindowDiv = leftWindowColl.Item(0)
    leftWindowDiv.scrollTop = leftWindowDiv.scrollHeight
End If
```

[image]

Because the class names seem to be generated (names like `sc-iqzUVk gZZIKO` look like generated) it could be difficult to find the appropriate `div` based on class name because the generated name will change. That is probably why you couldn't perform the scroll as you write in your comment. This can be solved by using the `querySelector` method as already suggested by @Florent B. More about [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

This selector selectes all divs inside element with id `app` which have style attribute ending with `scroll;`.

```
Dim selector As String
selector = "#app div[style$='scroll;']" 

Dim leftWindowDiv As HTMLDivElement
Set leftWindowDiv = html.querySelector(selector)
leftWindowDiv.scrollTop = leftWindowDiv.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the data is actually being loaded in the page via JavaScript (AJAX request), it might be easier to go directly to the source instead of scraping the data from the page... then you don't have to try to trigger the data refresh by scrolling.

E.g. This request...

```
https://www.quintoandar.com.br/api/search?q=(and%20vagas:%271%27(and%20area:[20,75](and%20custo:[500,4400]tipo:%27Apartamento%27)))&fq=local:[%27-23.442839332881825,-46.78368476621091%27,%27-23.658112332905105,-46.67382148496091%27]&return=id,foto_capa,aluguel,area,quartos,custo,photos,endereco,regiao_nome&size=12&q.parser=structured&expr.distance=floor(haversin(-23.550475832893465,-46.72875312558591,local.latitude,local.longitude))&expr.rank=relevance_score-(10000*distance)&sort=rank%20desc&start=12
```

...is being made behind the scenes and returns a JSON data packet with the matching data:

```
{"status":{"rid":"saDi7Y8s0eHFAgq6wiU=","time-ms":11},"hits":{"found":306,"start":12,"hit":[{"id":"892805064","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"70","id":"892805064","aluguel":"2096","foto_capa":"capa892805064283_95250575977DSC0029.jpg","photos":["892805064-283.95250575977DSC0029.jpg","892805064-40.179547677396954DSC0030.jpg","892805064-284.5837713474729DSC0031.jpg","892805064-902.2967820247848DSC0032.jpg","892805064-529.554508221606DSC0033.jpg"],"custo":"2528","endereco":"Avenida Diógenes Ribeiro de Lima","regiao_nome":"Alto da Lapa"}},{"id":"892815116","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"60","id":"892815116","aluguel":"2850","foto_capa":"capa892815116261_74899351456617DSC4227.JPG","photos":["892815116-261.74899351456617DSC4227.JPG","892815116-322.2261964874089DSC4229.JPG","892815116-797.408104831225DSC4230.JPG","892815116-755.9750463973334DSC4231.JPG","892815116-335.025196990966DSC4232.JPG"],"custo":"3476","endereco":"Rua Carlos Weber","regiao_nome":"Vila Leopoldina"}},{"id":"892814441","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"56","id":"892814441","aluguel":"2300","foto_capa":"capa892814441438_88057915637637DSC2877.JPG","photos":["892814441-438.88057915637637DSC2877.JPG","892814441-372.04023616269046DSC2879.JPG","892814441-544.1457767902004DSC2880.JPG","892814441-696.1076611567722DSC2881.JPG","892814441-658.147344161576DSC2882.JPG"],"custo":"3053","endereco":"Rua Schilling","regiao_nome":"Vila Leopoldina"}},{"id":"892801135","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"74","id":"892801135","aluguel":"2100","foto_capa":"capa892801135154_64867005243553DSC0131.jpg","photos":["892801135-154.64867005243553DSC0131.jpg","892801135-821.0691885230938DSC0132.jpg","892801135-550.173130870861DSC0133.jpg","892801135-781.6859738106783DSC0134.jpg","892801135-324.15549348830274DSC0135.jpg"],"custo":"2962","endereco":"Rua Cerro Corá","regiao_nome":"Vila Romana"}},{"id":"892810991","fields":{"quartos":"1","area":"44","id":"892810991","aluguel":"1700","foto_capa":"capa892810991346_72268700275674DSC7435.JPG","photos":["892810991-346.72268700275674DSC7435.JPG","892810991-760.5384685893431DSC7437.JPG","892810991-493.4367707205927DSC7438.JPG","892810991-148.3627701115735DSC7439.JPG","892810991-879.5681722331702DSC7440.JPG"],"custo":"2290","endereco":"Rua Filipinas","regiao_nome":"Alto da Lapa"}},{"id":"892785444","fields":{"quartos":"3","area":"72","id":"892785444","aluguel":"1750","foto_capa":"capa892785444176_87927661079405DSC0078cpia.jpg","photos":["892785444-176.87927661079405DSC0078cpia.jpg","892785444-155.2841769051142DSC0079cpia.jpg","892785444-264.8248449740238DSC0080cpia.jpg","892785444-271.50916660357717DSC0081cpia.jpg","892785444-73.63648677390611DSC0082cpia.jpg"],"custo":"2596","endereco":"Rua Aparande","regiao_nome":"Vila Romana"}},{"id":"892815084","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"65","id":"892815084","aluguel":"1400","foto_capa":"capa892815084151_12980286342614DSC0648.JPG","photos":["892815084-151.12980286342614DSC0648.JPG","892815084-366.4192232225364DSC0646.JPG","892815084-323.49030789818755DSC0647.JPG","892815084-57.91456171751297DSC0650.JPG","892815084-823.6616866177429DSC0651.JPG"],"custo":"1702","endereco":"Rua Professora Gioconda Mussolini","regiao_nome":"Butantã"}},{"id":"892815480","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"66","id":"892815480","aluguel":"1517","foto_capa":"capa892815480827_4216371362361MSA7050.jpg","photos":["892815480-827.4216371362361MSA7050.jpg","892815480-168.3833393977906MSA7051.jpg","892815480-628.7954363215526MSA7052.jpg","892815480-422.0828651677334MSA7053.jpg","892815480-145.77827866297056MSA7055.jpg"],"custo":"2537","endereco":"Avenida Diógenes Ribeiro de Lima","regiao_nome":"Alto da Lapa"}},{"id":"892803901","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"62","id":"892803901","aluguel":"2100","foto_capa":"capa892803901461_71112127633575DSC0020.jpg","photos":["892803901-461.71112127633575DSC0020.jpg","892803901-957.5988374372433DSC0019.jpg","892803901-451.9960408234817DSC0021.jpg","892803901-901.8494079400576DSC0022.jpg","892803901-246.9476745586001DSC0023.jpg"],"custo":"2522","endereco":"Avenida Manoel Pedro Pimentel","regiao_nome":"Centro"}},{"id":"892814536","fields":{"quartos":"1","area":"43","id":"892814536","aluguel":"3300","foto_capa":"capa892814536235_068855277688165andar1.JPG","photos":["892814536-235.068855277688165andar1.JPG","892814536-119.102637766625555andar2.JPG","892814536-597.02840920644885andar3.JPG","892814536-86.43842879346635andar6.JPG","892814536-748.15126030809735andar4.JPG"],"custo":"3981","endereco":"Rua Heitor Penteado","regiao_nome":"Vila Romana"}},{"id":"892817054","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"57","id":"892817054","aluguel":"2300","foto_capa":"capa892817054867_6528077345225MSA0543.jpg","photos":["892817054-867.6528077345225MSA0543.jpg","892817054-845.6187393316951MSA0542.jpg","892817054-580.6323230425363MSA0544.jpg","892817054-385.0217861332558MSA0545.jpg","892817054-638.0684371185209MSA0546.jpg"],"custo":"3246","endereco":"Rua Jericó","regiao_nome":"Vila Madalena"}},{"id":"892801625","fields":{"quartos":"2","area":"66","id":"892801625","aluguel":"2500","foto_capa":"capa892801625221_0775662268666THI0215.jpg","photos":["892801625-221.0775662268666THI0215.jpg","892801625-506.8116885746092THI0228.jpg","892801625-562.32705863531THI0218.jpg","892801625-194.33328511837655THI0219.jpg","892801625-980.9227287984841THI0220.jpg"],"custo":"3394","endereco":"Rua Guaricanga","regiao_nome":"Lapa"}}]}}
```

You can then use a [JSON parser for VBA](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to process the raw data rather than having to scrape the HTML and find what you're looking for.

Comment: OK, but isn't the purpose of your VBA code to extract the contents of the `<span id="app.components.HouseCard.rentLine">` which has the property name & price? Those pieces of data would be directly given to you via the JSON response, which means you don't need to pretend to be a web browser that's scrolling...

Comment: I don't really think this answer should be down-voted... it's an alternative way to pull out the data, seeing as though the purpose of the script is to scrape webpage data.