# Scroll automatically inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have a problem with my website.
I want to make a JavaScript function which scrolls down to an object with the id #important. Usually i just modify the link to page.html#important. but because the object is at the bottom of a div which has a scrollbar itself that won't work.

Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var timeout = setInterval(reloadChat, 10);  
    function reloadChat() {
        $("#chat").load("chat.php");
    }
    reloadChat();
</script>
```

and in chat.php i fetch rows from my database in which the last row is being displayed in a `<div id="lastmessage"></div>` which i want to scroll down to

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to provide code of what you've tried and what part you are stuck on.

Comment: agreed with @Leeish . This would be helpful for us to provide you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Element.scrollIntoView()` with behavior set to smooth.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```js
window.onload = function(e){ 
  var element = document.getElementById('second');
  element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

```css
#first {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#second {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#third {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

`behavior: 'smooth'` will quickly provide good UX.

You can choose when to call `element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });`. It will scroll to that DOM element when called.

Comment: If i try that i get this error from chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null
    at window.onload ((index):149)`, maybe because of the AJAX?

Comment: It says scrollIntoView of null because it didn't find an element with the ID you specified. It was caused by this: `var element = document.getElementById('second');`. Replace `second` with the ID of the div you want to scroll to.

Comment: Check the sample code I showed, again. You will get it solved up when you get the correct element saved in there.

Comment: i had done that, i think it's because the AJAX hasn't loaded at the window.onload trigger

Comment: Yes if the DOM element isn't in the DOM yet, that could cause something like that. Try reading this real quick and see if it helps you figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: With AJAX, also be aware of the callback function. The code that calls the scroll should be inside there. That could cause it also.

Comment: is there also something which lets it trigger the first time the AJAX is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know what you have or dont have, try this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: the ajax is added to the question and the page i'm loading is just a MySQLi fetch from db php script

Comment: I added it inside this code as ScrollDown() and now it works perfectly! thanks! `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    ScrollDown();
    $(document).unbind("ajaxComplete");
   });`

Answer (score 1):

Is .scrollIntoView() something like you want?
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Or maybe this can help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/270628/4335288

var objDiv = document.getElementById("important");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;